# Dojo to select  two nodes combine using dojo.query

Tags: dojo

How to select  two nodes combine using dojo.query

For example:

```
dojo.query("[name=bctaskAssignList] select")[0].innerHTML = "<option value=''>New</option>";
dojo.query("[name=bctodoList] select")[0].innerHTML = "<option value=''>New</option>";
```

some thing like

```
dojo.query("[name=bctaskAssignList] select","[name=bctodoList] select")[0].innerHTML = "<option value=''>New</option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
var nodeNames = ["bctaskAssignList", "bctodoList"];

dojo.map(nodeNames, function(nameValue) {
    return dojo.query("["+nameValue+"] select")[0];
}).forEach(function(node) {
    node.innerHTML = "<option value=''>New</option>";
});
```

However, a better solution would be to mark the `select` elements you're trying to access with a `class` attribute. Then you could use a single call to `dojo.query(...)`.